# Styling dropdown element in HTML

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Hi I want to change the style of the dropdown, nearer the option tags, in HTML. In Firefox it is working, but not properly in IE and google chrome.

The padding is only working in firefox. The background color is working on all browsers, but in IE you can see it, even on the selected value.

[Demo with JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHWuj/)

Html:

```
<label for="locale">locale:<em>*</em></label>
<select name="locale" id="locale">
    <option selected="selected">en_CA</option>
    <option>en_US</option>
    <option>fr_FR</option>
    <option>fr_CA</option>
    <option>ja_JP</option>
</select><br />
```

CSS:

```
label{
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

label em{
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

select{
    color: #333;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px -5px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 262px;
    border: #999 1px solid;
}

select option {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Best not to manipulate the select styles because you won't get cross browser support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome etc) don't allow padding on `select` elements. You can however mimic padding by manipulating the height for top and bottom padding and text-indent for left-padding.

Update: The same goes for background-color on `option` elements. Webkit doesn't allow that and I don't believe there's a workaround other than doing your own Javascript implementation of a drop-down using for example an unordered list and some styling.

Comment: height isn't working either. Only in firefox there is no problem.

Comment: height works fine for me in Chrome (at least on OS X). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b5m4G/

Comment: Oh sorry, I questioned wrong. I want to style the option tags and not the whole dropdown thing. Styling the dropdown box is no problem.

Comment: Then you're going to need to do your own implementation of a drop-down. The level of control you have over the appearance of the option tag is very limited. Also, consider smart phones and tablets that have a completely different implementation of drop-downs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you could just style the option tags. I think I read it from somewhere that it is based on OS or something...